# How to show Form Sheet from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift

The `AppDelegate` checks whether the user is logged in or not, and if not, shows the `formSheet view` from wherever the user is in the application.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the window property like `rootViewController` in appdelegate class

Try this:-

```
if let rootVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? YourViewController {
        //Add the code here to present signupviewcontroller as form sheet
}
```

if your rootVC is `UINavigationController` than use `visibleViewController` property of  `UINavigationController`

```
if let nsvigationVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController  {
        if yourVC = nsvigationVC.visibleViewController {
            //Add the code here to present signupviewcontroller as form sheet
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: “Main”, bundle: nil) //get signupviewcontroller from storyboard
            let signupVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("signupviewcontroller") as! signupviewcontroller
            signupVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet
            signupVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 365, height: 500) // set content size as per your requirement
            yourVC.presentViewController(signupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Comment: This assumes the root controller is the topmost view controller. Based on the question, this may not always be the case.

Comment: What would be the code to present `signupviewcontroller` as form sheet?

Comment: @Berry checkout updated code. i have added code to present `signupviewcontroller` as form sheet